# Creating a new iterator object every time I traverse the list

Tags: java, iterator

If I create an Iterator object on any List, do I have to create a new iterator object every time I traverse the list? Or do new items added or removed from the list automatically get accounted for by the previously created iterator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Iterator` is a one-use utility.  You generally need a new one each time you iterate through the list.  However, that's not a bad thing; `Iterator`s have very little state (for an `ArrayList`, it might be just an int to hold the current index).

If the backing list is modified in between iterator calls, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException` from the iterator operation.  Adding or removing items must be done using the `Iterator` itself.